# How the user can edit the form fields after submitting the form in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, forms

I am working on WordPress Website. I want the user will first register and after registration, The user will fill the form after submitting the form the user can edit the form fields in the user account.

I have used some plugins like user profile and ultimate member but I am not able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ThemeMyLogin Plugin. It is very useful and Solves the Problem.